# Passing SSRS Dataset Parameters on the fly

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008

I have a SSRS 2008 tabular report with a drill down group by.  The group by is the AssignedAnalystId.  In the Database and server only the AssignedAnalystId is available.  I have another database on another server that has the table with the mapping between the AssignedAnalystId and there actual name (Full User Name).

What I want to do is to be able to pass in the AssignedAnalystId on the fly to the other dataset as if it were a scalar function and get the full username to show in the group instead of the AssignedAnalystId.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you would want to join the tables in your initial query, but you can have two separate datasets in your report and use the Lookup function to do what you need. The Lookup function takes 4 parameters; in your case you would fill in: ID field from the 1st dataset, ID field from the second dataset, username field from the second dataset, the name of the dataset. See the MSDN article for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210531.aspx

A good way to filter your data is to use a Split function. Set your SSRS parameter to be comma separated values or even multi-valued and then you can use the table-valued function below to turn it into a temp table for use in your query:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Split (@origString varchar(max))     
returns @temptable TABLE (items varchar(max))     
as     
begin     
    declare @idx int     
    declare @split varchar(max)     
    set @idx = 1     
    if datalength(@origString )<1 or @origString is null
        return     

    while @idx <> 0     
    begin     
        set @idx = charindex(',', @origString)     
        if @idx <> 0     
            set @split = left(@origString, @idx - 1)     
        else     
            set @split = @origString

        if(datalength(@split) > 0)
            insert into @temptable(Items) values(ltrim(rtrim(@split)))

        set @origString = right(@origString, datalength(@origString) - @idx)     
        if datalength(@origString) = 0
            break     
    end 
return     
end
```

Then your query could would include something like this to act as a filter:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 as T1
INNER JOIN Split(@SSRScsvParameter) as T2 on T1.ID = T2.ID
```

Comment: I like this solution. Another thing that has been requested of me is to be able to limit the report based on a list or array passed in. In SQL something like SELECT * FROM a WHERE a.b_Id IN(SELECT Id FROM c). The problem that I am having now is that although I created a stored procedure where I am passing a user-defined table type in, I cannot pass it as a parameter via Reporting Services. Anyone know of a work around for this? I thought of using a DataSet as a Reporting Services Data Source but have not found any recent examples for that.

Comment: I like this and think it will work well for me.  It would be nice if I could pass a user-defined table type but this is actually better in that it is more generic and I can now use the split function in more places.